# Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 3 of the expression [{{book.rating}} > 0 && {{book.rating}} <= 5]

Tags: json, angularjs, http

Как могу фильтровать все 5 звездов должны показывают с зависимостью от рейтинга из JSON?

Должен показать как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал краткий пример, [здесь](https://plnkr.co/edit/U3gMp0CSejPuWftb1n7o?p=preview)

`обзор`

Comment: Пример не работает минимум по двум причинам. А ещё он должен бы быть в вопросе.

Comment: давай позволять мне как изменить вопросы по теме